# Python urllib2 response

Tags: python, urllib2

Okay so I'm currently sending a post request to a website which then outputs a response in html, I don't want to `print` the entire page, just specific content within some div brackets..

example of content i want to output

```
<td align="right"> example </td>
```

so I only want to output " example " within the td brackets, how would I do this?

Comment: I suggest you looking into beautifulsoup. You can select elements by css etc.

Comment: You can try `BeautifulSoup`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are quite new to Python/programming in general.

I recommend `requests` over built in `urllib2` as it is easier to use.

For element selection, I think `beautifulsoup` is one of the simplest libraries to use.

Both are easy to install:

1. `pip install requests`
2. `pip install beautifulsoup4`

Code:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Unicode/List_of_useful_symbols'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
tds = soup.findAll("td") # you can extract tags like <div> as well
print(tds)
td_texts = [td.text for td in tds] # in case you are interested in the text only
```

Output:

```
[<td style="vertical-align:top">§</td>, <td> 00A7 section</td>, <td style="vertical-align:top">¶</td>, <td> 00B6 paragraph</td>, <td style="vertical-align:top">·</td>,
```

Answer (score 1):

HTMLParser is designed for this task.  You can feed it the entire HTML response pages.  It will then call methods (which you will override in a subclass) for the entry of a tag (which you then check to make sure it is a td tag with attribute "right"), another method for the data (which will be a string "example" and another method for the end tag (which you can use to stop doing anything with the data methods.

I love HTMLParser.  Check it out.

Edited to add a sketched example:

```
class MyParser(HTMLParser):
# Looking for <td class="example">
#               data here
#             </td>

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyParser, self).__init__()
        self.in_td = False
        self.data = ''

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag != 'td':
            return
        d = dict(attrs)
        if 'class' in d and d['class'] == 'example':
            self.in_td = True

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        if tag=='td' and self.in_td:
            self.in_td = False
            print("Found this data: {}".format(self.data))

    def handle_data(self, data):
        if self.in_td:
            self.data += data
```